# What can be used instead of #using if I don't use C++/CLI?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

I am following a tutorial to use Microsoft SQL Server (I am forced to use this), and the examples use #using , among other, in order to work.

I saw that if I need to configure Visual Studio to support CLR, but then I got different errors I'd like not to debug. Is there a way to make it work without CLR ?

I tried to find these dll in my computer, to add them in the project folder and to add these dependencies in the configuration but it didn't work. Moreover, there are several version of these dll in different folder in the computer (I don't know if I should use one more than another), and there is no lib. At least none I could find.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What tutorial? What examples? It isn't clear what you are trying to do. You can clearly call SQL Server without C++/CLI, but it is probably more complex.

Comment: Once upon a time, with Visual C++ + MFC, we used `CDatabase` and related classes.

Comment: Here there is the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wtdsdkh.aspx) with a list of "legacy techniques" for accessing Data Access.

Comment: You need to either follow the tutorial you have found and use CLR, or find another resources (see above comments) and use native C++. Using a tutorial for CLR and trying to code in in C++ clearly isn't going to work.

Comment: I was following this tutorial :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308510/how-to-update-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-sqldataadapter-object-in-visual-c-.net

Comment: Which is about "Visual C++ .NET", so you need to use the CLR to follow that tutorial. Maybe another question with the errors you get when you try to use it would sort you out?

Comment: Other example with another technology, ADO (not ADO.NET): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/ado-code-examples-in-visual-c